# Error deploying Alexa Skill to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, cloud, jovo-framework

I appreciate the simplicity with which the jovo-framework developers are explaining their tutorials.
Having finished building my skill, using this great framework, I am now trying to deploy it on Heroku. I followed this tutorial:
[How to Deploy your Alexa Skill and Google Action to Heroku](https://www.jovo.tech/blog/deploy-to-heroku/#introduction)

I believe I have done all the necessary steps as demanded. But when I run this in the console:

```
heroku open
```

the app doesn't work and I get these errors on the console:
[image]

I am really looking forward to publish my skill and finally see the fruits of my work.
So if anyone knows what might be causing this error, I would totally appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `npm start` script needs to do `node index.js --webhook` instead of `node index.js`.

The old one was pre Jovo `v1.0`, forgot to change this in one part of the tutorial. Updated now: [How to Deploy your Alexa Skill and Google Action to Heroku > Updating the Package.json](https://www.jovo.tech/blog/deploy-to-heroku/#updating-the-package-json).